# ¿Cómo limitar el scroll de un div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy haciendo un configurador, donde el cliente solicito que una tabla que se va armando dependiendo de lo que va escogiendo, lo acompañe mientras le da scroll, este es parte de mi HTML, donde se va armando imagen + tabla

HTML

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
      <div id="sticky" style="position: sticky;">
        <div id="no" style="display:none;">
          <img id="laimg" src="" style="position: absolute;width: 310px;height:230px;" />
        </div>
        <div id="results" style="position: absolute; width: 400px;">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Mi detalle es, estoy usando este codigo para permitir el scroll:

Javascript:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});

var dir = 1;
var MIN_TOP = 200;
var MAX_TOP = 350;

function autoscroll() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + dir;
    if (window_top >= MAX_TOP) {
        window_top = MAX_TOP;
        dir = -1;
    } else if (window_top <= MIN_TOP) {
        window_top = MIN_TOP;
        dir = 1;
    }
    $(window).scrollTop(window_top);
    window.setTimeout(autoscroll, 100);
}
```

Este funciona correctamente, sin embargo, se posiciona encima del footer de la pagina, hay forma de bloquear que no pase del footer?

Ya intente poniendo otro div anchor, tambien busque acerca del window.height, pero no veo forma de limitar el scroll.

Comment: Y si usas css y aplicas un `overflow-y` a tu elemento `<div>` donde armas tu tabla?

Answer (score 1):

La causa del problema es el uso del estilo `position:absolute`. Trata de reemplazar ambos `position:absolute` por `position:relative` o eliminarlos:

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky" style="position: sticky;">
   <div id="no" style="display:none;">
      <img id="laimg" src="" style="position: relative;width: 310px;height:230px;" />
   </div>
   <div id="results" style="position: relative; width: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, esto no funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Tenía el mismo problema, checa esto: http://jsfiddle.net/86Zp7/2/

(Ver en pantalla completa el siguiente código)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    relative_scroll(".article", ".side");
});

function relative_scroll(parent, item) {
  if ($(item).length) {
   var parent_height = $(parent).height() + parseInt($(parent).css("padding-bottom"));
   var parent_offset = $(parent).offset().top;
   var window_height = $(window).height();
   var element_height = $(item).height();
   var doc_scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

   var progress = (doc_scroll - parent_offset) / (parent_height - window_height);

   if (progress < 0) { progress = 0; }
   if (progress > 1) { progress = 1; }

   var scroll = (progress * ((parent_height + parseInt($(parent).css("margin-top"))) - element_height));
   if (scroll < 0) { scroll = 0; }

   if (element_height < parent_height) {
    if (parseInt(scroll + element_height) < parent_height) {
     $(item).css("margin-top", scroll +"px");
    } else {
     $(item).css("margin-top", (parseInt(parent_height) + parseInt($(parent).css("margin-top"))) - (element_height) +"px");
    }
   }
  }
}
```

```css
.main {
    height:1500px;
    width:800px;
}

.article {
    display:inline-block;
    width:500px;
    height:1500px;
    background-color:black;
}

.side {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color:red;
}

.footer, .header {
    height:200px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="article">
    </div><div class="side">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

¡Ojalá te sirva!